# Compute Subtotal of POS

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

So I'm creating a project, which is a Point of Sale, like those in fast food chains.

The buttons on my POS is created dynamically, depends on the values from my database, and now I'm having a hard time to compute the subtotal when I change the quantity of each item. I used DataGrid to list all the products ordered by the customer.

I created two buttons which is `add` and `minus` that can set the quantity of the selected row in the datagridview, I'm not sure if I got it right but the code is also provided below which computes the price of the selected item multiplied to the quantity.

My problem is, how can I compute the subtotal price, and the total quantity of items in my datagridview everytime I add items in my datagrid or I add or subtract in the quantity of the item.? The subtotal should reflect immediately EVERYTIME I add an item, or add or subtract an item.

Provided is a sample image to understand better what I want to happen in my project.

[image: LINK TO INTERFACE]

```
public void quantity_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        if (row == null || row.Index < 0)
            return;
        var unit = (sender == add) ? 1 : -1;

        var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value) + unit;

        row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = quantity;
        var rate = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["SellingPrice"].Value);
        row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value = quantity * rate;
    }
```

---

```
private void frmPOS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        add.Click += quantity_change;
        minus.Click += quantity_change;

        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblmenu", dbConn);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = rdr["menuName"].ToString();
            btn.Name = rdr["menuID"].ToString();
            btn.Width = 126;
            btn.Height = 80;

            btn.Click += delegate
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

                MySqlConnection cnn2 = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn.connString);
                cnn2.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT menuName, menuPrice FROM tblmenu WHERE menuID = @id", cnn2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", btn.Name);
                MySqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr2.Read())
                {
                   //I added the item in my datagridview, with the button name, 1 = 1quantity, and Selling Price
                 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr2.GetString("menuName").ToUpper(), 1, rdr2.GetDouble("menuPrice"));
                }

                //I copied the value of Selling Price Column to the Total Price Column in this part
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    value = row.Cells["SellingPrice"].Value.ToString();
                    row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value = value;
                }
            };


            if (rdr["menuAvailability"].ToString() == "yes")
            {
                if (rdr["menuCategory"].ToString() == "Sandwiches")
                {
                    flpSandwiches.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
                else if (rdr["menuCategory"].ToString() == "Appetizers")
                {
                    flpAppetizers.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
            }               
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see in your quantity_change method:

```
row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value = quantity * rate;
```

for me it is subtotal for given product.

You you wan't to calculate total price of whole order (all products in data grid) you need to sum all subtotals for all products.

For example, at the end of quantity_Change:

```
double Total=0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    Total+=row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value;
}

// now you can set this value for example label under data grid
labelTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
```

Comment: Wow! That works. I just created this as a function so that I can call it even when I add or remove item! Thanks! :)